# Using Fourier transform on a finite interval to prove a formula

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

In the book Controllability of Partial Diﬀerential Equations by Enrique Zuazua page 110 I have found a problem  to prove the last equality in the last line formula $$\sum\limits_{n,m} {{a_n}{{\bar a}_m}K({\mu _n} - {\mu _m})}. $$
I tried to use the Fourier transform of $e^{ixt}$ in $S'(R)$ to prove it but I found $$\sum\limits_{n,m} {{a_n}{a_m}K({\mu _n} + {\mu _m})}. $$
(With plus sign).
Any Ideas? Thank you.

> Define the function
>   $$
>          h
>   \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},
>   \quad  h(t)
>   =      \begin{cases}
>            \cos(t/2) & \text{if $|t| \leq \pi$}, \\
>            0         & \text{if $|t| > \pi$}.
>          \end{cases}
> $$
>   and let us compute its Fourier transform $K(\varphi)$,
>   $$
>     K(\varphi)
>   = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(t) e^{i t \varphi} \,\mathrm{d}t
>   = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t) e^{i t \varphi} \,\mathrm{d}t
>   = \frac{4 \cos \pi \varphi}{1 - 4 \varphi^2}.
> $$
>   On the other hand, since $0 \leq h(t) \leq 1$ for any $t \in [-\pi, \pi]$, we have that
>   $$
>   \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left| \sum_n a_n e^{i \mu_n t} \right|^2
>   \,\mathrm{d}t
>   \geq
>   \int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t) \left| \sum_n a_n e^{i \mu_n t} \right|^2 
>   \,\mathrm{d}t
>   =
>   \sum_{n,m} a_n \overline{a}_m K(\mu_n - \mu_m)
>   =
> $$
>
> (Original picture of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2OvY.jpg).)

Answer (score 2):

We have :

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t) \left\vert \sum_n a_n e^{i\phi_nt} \right\vert^2 dt=\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t)  \sum_n a_n e^{i\phi_nt}  \overline{\sum_m a_m e^{i\phi_mt}}dt.$$
Since :

$$\sum_n a_n e^{i\phi_nt}  \overline{\sum_m a_m e^{i\phi_mt}}=\sum_{n,m} a_n \overline{a_m} e^{i(\phi_n-\phi_m)t}.$$

Then :

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t) \left\vert \sum_n a_n e^{i\phi_nt} \right\vert^2 dt=\sum_{n,m} a_n \overline{a_m}\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t) e^{i(\phi_n-\phi_m)t}dt=\sum_{n,m} a_n \overline{a_m}K(\phi_n-\phi_m).$$